# Including custom elements in Log4J2 XML configuration

Tags: log4j2

I am writing code which will work with Log4J2 loggers, but which is not itself directly part of the framework (not a `Logger`, `Appender`, `Layout` etc.).
This code needs configuring and I was wondering if the existing Log4J2 configuration system (which seems very extensible) would support this?

My idea was to write a new type of `@Plugin` which would read nodes in the XML configuration file and convert them into a custom options class.

```java
@Plugin(name = "options", category = Node.CATEGORY, printObject = true)
public final class Log4jOptions {
  private final Options actualOptions;

  Log4jOptions(Map<String, String> keyValueMap) {
    this.actualOptions = Options.of(keyValueMap::get);
  }

  public Options getOptions() {
    return actualOptions;
  }

  @PluginFactory
  public static Log4jOptions createOptions(@PluginElement("Options") Log4jOption[] options) {
    HashMap<String, String> keyValueMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Log4jOption opt : options) {
      String name = Options.checkName(opt.getName());
      String value = opt.getValue();
      if (value.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("option values must not be empty");
      }
      keyValueMap.put(name, value);
    }
    return new Log4jOptions(keyValueMap);
  }
}
```

and:

```java
@Plugin(name = "option", category = Node.CATEGORY, printObject = true)
public class Log4jOption {
  @PluginFactory
  public static Log4jOption createOption(
      @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
      @PluginValue(value = "value", substitute = false) String value) {
    return new Log4jOption(name, value);
  }

  private final String name;
  private final String value;

  Log4jOption(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

and then in `log4j2.xml`:

```xml
<Configuration status="trace">
    ...
    <Options>
        <option name="foo">bar</option>
    </Options>
</Configuration>
```

However on trying this I see no way to actually obtain the instance (e.g. by calling a Log4J plugin class to create it) and I see no evidence that the Log4J initialization created it automatically (I do see the other parts of the config being created).

I even tried calling the `PluginBuilder` directly, but that wants me to pass in the `Node` hierarchy, which I don't think I have access to:

```java
  Log4jOptions optionsPlugin = (Log4jOptions) new PluginBuilder(optionsType)
      .withConfiguration(configuration)
      .withConfigurationNode(node)   // <-- I don't know how to get this.
      .build();
```

So my questions are:

1. Most importantly, is trying to use Log4J config to configure a non-framework class (i.e. not a logger, appender etc.) a bad idea?
2. If it is supported, what am I doing wrong?

Note: I know about the `Properties` element, but while my config will start out simple, I think it will outgrow a simple key/value setup and I wanted to see if it's possible to use more structured XML for it. If it's not a good idea to try and do what I'm doing, I'll just do it in a separate file with a filename in a property.